# Возможен ли парсинг ТГ каналов?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Интересует следующий вопрос: возможен ли парсинг аудитории телеграмм каналов, в которых я не являюсь администратором? Если это возможно, то должен ли я состоять в этих каналах или нет?
То, что можно собирать записи с каналов я знаю, вопрос только на счет аудитории, получении id, nickname.
Если это возможно, то подскажите как это возможно реализовать, желательно на Python.
Так же мне говорили, что это возможно при помощи telethon, но как именно сделать в документации к библиотеке не нашел. Не могли бы вы подсказать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я бы попробовал поразбираться с `telethon` через `from telethon.sync import TelegramClient`, для интереса делал вывод текущих диалогов юзера: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f67040e8ba3092b747bb58b6c49f3d980feb52e7/telegram__telethon__examples/print_dialogs.py#L17 Но наверняка, можно заглянуть внутри диалогов и собирать сообщения и прочую инфу

Comment: gil9red - с чатами и диалогами это можно делать, меня интересуют именно каналы, как, допустим из канала "А" у которого 150 подписчиков, вытащить id и nickname этих подписчиков, при этом я состою в этом канале, но не являюсь его админом

Answer (score 1):

Увы, в телеграме список подписчиков канала виден только администраторам. Никакие решения не помогут их увидеть.